# How can I list all image URLs inside a GCP project with an API?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to write an application in GO that will get all the image vulnerabilities inside a GCP project for me using the [Container Analysis API](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/reference/rest).

The [GO Client library](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/reference/libraries) for this API has the function `findVulnerabilityOccurrencesForImage()` to do this, however it requires you to pass the URL of the image you want to get the vulnerability report from in the form `resourceURL := "https://gcr.io/my-project/my-repo/my-image"` and the projectID. This means that if there are multiple images in your project, you have to list and store them first and only after that you can recursively call the `findVulnerabilityOccurrencesForImage()` function to get ALL of the vulnerabilities.

So I need a way to get and store all of the images' URLs inside all of the repos inside a given GCP project, but so far I couldn't find a solution. I can easily do that in the CLI by running `gcloud container images list` command but I don't see a way how that can be done with an API.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Cloud Storage](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage) package and the `Objects` method to do so. For example:

```golang
func GetURLs() ([]string, error) {
    bucket := "bucket-name"
    urls := []string{}
    results := client.Bucket(bucket).Objects(context.Background(), nil)

    for {
        attrs, err := results.Next()
        if err != nil {
            if err == iterator.Done {
                break
            }

            return nil, fmt.Errorf("iterating results: %w", err)
        }

        urls = append(urls, fmt.Sprint("https://storage.googleapis.com", "/", bucket, "/", attrs.Name))
    }

    return urls, nil
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
Does this code return VM images or Docker images?
Because for my application I need Docker images which have the URL form `https://gcr.io/my-project/my-repo/my-image`, whereas this script returns URLs in the form `https://storage.googleapis.com/repo-name/containers/images/my-image`.

Comment: Just can just modify the line `urls = append(urls, fmt.Sprint("https://storage.googleapis.com", "/", bucket, "/", attrs.Name))` to match the structure you need